# Elegant way to iterate in C++

Tags: c++, vector, coding-style

Let's say I have a vector of Polygons, where each polygon contains a vector of Points. I have to iterate over all the points of all the polygons many times in my code, I end up having to write the same code over and over again:

```
for(std::vector<Polygon*>::const_iterator polygon = polygons.begin();
                polygon != polygons.end(); polygon++)
{
        for(std::vector<Point>::const_iterator point = (*polygon)->points.begin();
                        point != (*polygon)->points.end(); point++)
        {
                (*point).DoSomething();
        }
}
```

I really feel that is a lot of code for two simple iterations, and feel like it's clogging the code and interfering with the readability.

Some options I thought are:

- using #defines - but it would make unportable (to use in other parts of the code). Furthermore, #defines are considered evil nowadays;
- iterate over vector->size() - it doesn't seem the most elegant way;
- calling a method with a function pointer - but in this case, the code that should be inside of the loop would be far from the loop.

So, what would be the most clean and elegant way of doing this?

Comment: With C++11, `auto` would clean this up dramatically.  Also for_each()...

Comment: Ranged-for is another option.

Comment: In c++11 you have [range-based for-loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for-loop)

Comment: Defining a segmented iterator wrapper would be nice, but it results in one extra comparison per iteration that compilers have a hard time removing.

Comment: @jozefg Is `(*polygon)`, because `(*polygon)` is the object and `polygon` is the iterator.

Comment: @AndréWagner I noticed that 10sec after I posted, whoops

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In C++11, using [ranged-base for loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for-loop) and the [`auto`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Type_inference) keyword:

```
for(const auto& polygon : polygons) {
    for(const auto& point : polygon->points) {
        point.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndréWagner be careful about over-use of `auto`, because it can lead to lack of documentation about what the hell types are being used.  :)

Answer (score 9):

If you can't use C++11, boost has a [FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/foreach.html) macro which generates a lot of code but dramatically simplifies your code:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(Polygon * polygon, polygons)
{
    BOOST_FOREACH( Point & point, polygon->points )
    {
        point.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The inner loop can be rewritten using algorithms like this:

```
std::for_each(
    (*polygon)->points.begin(), (*polygon)->points.end(), 
    &Point::DoSomething
);
```

Mixing this with the outer loop is a bit more complex:

```
std::for_each(
    polygons.begin(), polygons.end(),
    []( Polygon* polygon ) {
        std::for_each(
            polygon->points.begin(), polygon->points.end(), 
            &Point::DoSomething
        );
    }
);
```

If we had some kind of compound iterator we could really express your intent, which is to *do* something *for each* point in *each* polygon. And a *range* library like *Boost.Range* would allow you to avoid naming each container twice, given that you want to work with their entire *range*.

My ideal version of your code would look like this:

```
for_each( flatten( polygons ), &Point::DoSomething );
```

were `flatten` would return a *view* of every `Point` in every `Polygon` as if it were a single continuous *range*. Note that this is something that can be accomplished in plain *C++03*, and all we are missing from *Boost.Range* to accomplish it is a *flatenning range*, which shouldn't be difficult to implement in terms of range `join`.

Otherwise, the *range-based for-loop* together with `auto` will help you reduce the boilerplate of iterating throw a range and forgetting about the complicated types.

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use C++11, maybe typedef the iterator type to something shorter like

```
typedef std::vector<Polygon*>::const_iterator PolyCit;
for (PolyCit polygon = polygons.begin(); polygon != polygons.end(); polygon++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, this won't work for you since you have a vector of pointers at the top level, but I'll keep it up, because I think it's pretty cool.

---

My template metaprogramming is a bit rusty, so there might be a simpler way to do this, but:

```
template<typename C, typename F, size_t depth>
struct nested_for_each_helper
{
    static void do_it(C& c, F& f)
    {
        for (auto& i : c)
            nested_for_each_helper<decltype(i),F,depth-1>::do_it(i,f);
    }
};

template<typename C, typename F>
struct nested_for_each_helper<C,F,0>
{
    static void do_it(C& c, F& f)
    {
        f(c);
    }
};

template<size_t depth, typename C, typename F>
void nested_for_each(C& c, F& f)
{
    nested_for_each_helper<C,F,depth>::do_it(c,f);
}

int main()
{        
    int n[3][3][3][3];
    int i = 0;
    nested_for_each<4>(n,[&i](int& n) { n = i++; });
    nested_for_each<4>(n,[](int n){
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    });
}
```

For your case, you can use it like this (no you can't):

```
nested_for_each<2>(polygons, [](Point const& p) { p.DoSomething(); });
```

Comment: `points` doesn't appear anywhere (yes, he has a complication on top of nested iteration).

Answer (score 1):

You need a layer of abstraction. Instead of dealing with a vector of polygons, write a class that manages that vector. The class then provides iterator pairs for iterating over the points. The code in the iterator knows and encapsulates those details.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's the plain old integer-based loop. A bit shorter than iterators.

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < polygons.size() ; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0 ; j < polygons[i]->points.size(); j++)
    {
        Point* p = polygons[i]->points[j] ;
        p->DoSomething();
    }
}
```

If you don't like that, and you don't have C++11 available, you can write function that accepts a functor (these were in C++0x under `std::tr1` I believe):

```
void eachPoint( function<void (Point* p)> func )
{
    for( int i = 0 ; i < polygons.size() ; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0 ; j < polygons[i]->points.size(); j++)
        {
            Point* p = polygons[i]->points[j] ;
            func(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, a plain old macro:

```
#define EACH_POLYGON( polyCollection ) for( int _polyI = 0 ; _polyI < polyCollection.size() ; _polyI++ ) \
for( int _ptNo = 0, Point* p=polyCollection[_polyI]->points[0] ; j < polyCollection[_polyI]->points.size() && (p=polyCollection[_polyI]->points[_ptNo]); _ptNo++)

EACH_POLYGON( polyCollection )
{
    p->DoSomething();
}
```